# Windows 7 cannot access network PC after name changed

Tags: windows-7, networking

My PC was able to be accessed by other PC on the network without any problem before. But now, after I renamed my PC, other PC cannot access to my PC. When they try to access, they will see a popup dialog box requiring them to enter network password.

Why is it after rename the PC, others cannot access it? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you changed your computer name, the other computers cache (locally stored password) is wrong as it's pointing on your old computer name.

### Example

My computer, **A** shares files on the network.

Computer **B** connects to **A** and types in a username/password. This username/password is now cached locally and computer **B** no longer have to type it in each time.

*2 years later*

I change my computer name to **C**.
Computer **B** connects to computer **C**. Since it's the first time Computer **B** talks to **C**, naturally it will be asked for a username/password.
After entering a username/password, this will once again be cached locally and machine **B** no longer have to enter username/password each time.